# AWS CLI create lambda function cannot see my zip file that is in S3 "No such file or directory"

Tags: amazon-s3, lambda

My first attempt was using the console and it worked. I have a new zip file that successfully uploaded to my bucket in S3. I can list the bucket and see both files there but when I try to use CLI to create the Lambda function it returns "Error parsing parameter '--zip-file': Unable to load paramfile"..." No such file or directory:"

I expect from the documentation that "fileb://path/to/file.zip" implies that the bucket name be included but I am unsure if the region URL is needed. I tried it with and without the region URL with the same results.

Again, I am able to use these file if I create the Lambda using the console, but not CLI. What am I missing?

```
[royce@localhost ~]$ aws s3 ls s3://uploads.lai
2017-08-18 10:27:48   60383836 userpermission-1.zip
2017-08-31 07:43:50   60389082 userpermission-4.zip
2017-08-18 14:15:43       1171 userpermission.db
[royce@localhost ~]$ aws lambda create-function --function-name awstest01 --zip-file "fileb://uploads.lai/userpermission-4.zip" --runtime java8 --role execution-role-arn --handler app.handler

Error parsing parameter '--zip-file': Unable to load paramfile fileb://uploads.lai/userpermission-4.zip: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'uploads.lai/userpermission-4.zip'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `--zip-file` flag is if you are uploading your function from a local zip file.

If you are using S3, the CLI the command should be something along the lines of `aws create function --code "S3Bucket=string,S3Key=string,S3ObjectVersion=string"`

You may check the reference here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/create-function.html

Comment: That worked. I also had the wrong syntax for the role but fixed it and now my function is in Lambda.